# Firebase search query returning empty result

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, collections, google-cloud-firestore

I want to see if "chefId"(encircled field of screenshot) exist in any of the document in a "chefCollection" or not. For this purpose I am writing below query.

```
Future<bool> checkChefID(String userID) async {
    
final chefCheck = (await Firestore.instance.collection('chef')
            .document("chefId")
            .collection("chef")
            .where("chefID", isEqualTo: userID)
            .getDocuments())
        .documents;

    print("Query result:  " + chefCheck.toString());
    chefCheck.length > 0 ? return true : return false;

  }
```

In above function this(rhnKjYg2yMhf5IVjI0zvTi7Mjpn2) is passed as userID parameter.

And it definitly exist in the chef collection

[image]

This is the result that I am getting for print statement

```dart
I/flutter (20455): Query result []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
final chefCheck = (await Firestore.instance.collection('chef')
            .document("chefId")
            .collection("chef")
            .where("chefID", isEqualTo: userID)
            .getDocuments())
        .documents;
```

into this:

```
final chefCheck = (await Firestore.instance.collection('chef')
            .where("chefID", isEqualTo: userID)
            .getDocuments())
        .documents;
```

In your database, you have a collection called `chef` and a field inside the document called `chefID`, therefore you shouldnt have `.document("chefId").collection("chef")`

Comment: Oops. My bad. Thanks Peter :)

Comment: Can you tell me what query should I write to extract all the feilds of certain document of collection along with keys and values? I am new with Firebase queries. I am struggling to do it.

Comment: @FaizanKamal please ask it as another question with explanation and code that you used, link it here so i can check it